# Programatically Add Slack User

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm running an end to end test of a bot that processes an event and creates a Slack channel based on the event, including inviting users. For the end to end test, I'd like to create a few users that I can invite to the channel, but thus far I've only found a method for inviting a user in the API. Is there no method or workaround to just create one?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create users on your workspace by posting to the `/User` endpoint of the SCIM API, though you will need to be on the Business+ or Enterprise Grid plans.

More information here: https://api.slack.com/scim#post-users

Answer (score -1):

It would seem the answer is "no", there is no method for programmatically adding a slack user.

Comment: This seems to just reiterate the previous answer, but with a lot less detail. Instead, consider accepting the existing answer.